# Characteristic lines of a PDE

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations, vectors

I'm reading Strauss's PDE book on page 6. Here we have the PDE $$au_x + bu_y = 0$$

This equation implies, that our solution $u(x,y)$ must be such, that its directional derivative in the direction of $\bar{v}=(a,b)$ must be zero. Or, $u(x,y)$ is constant in the direction of $\bar{v}$. The following sentence is confusing to me : " The lines parallel to $\bar{v}$ have the equations $$bx-ay = constant"$$

What lines is he referring to? Does he perhaps mean vectors of the form $(x,y)$ in $\Bbb{R^2}$? But if thats the case, then the above equation should have zero instead of a constant value, since the expression on the left is the determinant of a $2x2$ matrix, whose columns are the vectors $(a,b)$ and $(x,y)$. Determinant zero means these vectors are dependent, and must be parallel. We are also given the orthogonal complement of $\bar{v}$, $(b,-a)$.

Comment: Well, the lines in the $(x,y)$-plane that are parallel to the vector $(a,b)$, of course. (As it's written.)

Comment: For different values of the constant, you get different lines. But they are all parallel (to each other, and to the vector $(a,b)$).